# How can I open an image in new div when hovering over it?

Tags: html, css

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.a1:hover{
width:300;
height:400;

}
.a2{
width:90%;
height:400px;
float:right;
border:5px solid red;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class=a2></div>
<div><img src="image1.jpg" width=100 height=100 class=a1 ></div>
<div><img src="image2.jpg" width=100 height=100 class=a1></div>
<div><img src="image3.jpg" width=100 height=100 class=a1 ></div>
<div><img src="image3.jpg" width=100 height=100 class=a1></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have four images,each one in a separate div.When hovering over one image, I need it to open in a new div with larger size (Keeping the first image as is) and i want to display some text under the new image that appears after hovering.
I've tried this but it seems that when hovering over the first image it got bigger but doesn't open in the targeted div. What can I do?

Comment: You'd need to write some JavaScript.

Comment: Are you trying to make a [light box](http://fancybox.net/) effect?

Comment: I need it as a way for presenting some news.A column of images on the left and by hovering over one image it will get bigger on the left with the news related to that image under it.

Answer (score 4):

You won't necessarily need Javascript for this.  The code snippet below  displays a larger version of the image when hovered while keeping the original image as is.

```css
.a1:hover{
width:300;
height:400;

}

.small-image {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

.small-image:hover + .large-image {
  visibility: visible;
}

.large-image {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-icons/4096/stackoverflow-4096-black.png" class="small-image">
     <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-icons/4096/stackoverflow-4096-black.png" class="large-image">
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this the sort of thing you wanted? You'll see I used a little bit of JS.

```js
var thumbSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb'),
    windowSelect = document.querySelector('.window'),
    thumbCount;

for (thumbCount = 0; thumbCount < thumbSelect.length; thumbCount++) {
    thumbSelect[thumbCount].onmouseover = function() {
        windowSelect.src = this.src;
    };
};
```

```css
.thumb {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.thumb:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.a2 {
    width:calc(100% - 115px);
    height:300px;
    float:right;
    border:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
  

<div class=a2>
    <img src="" width=300 height=300 class="window">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.canbypublications.com/sihanoukville-cambodia/sihanoukville-page-images/ph-beach-independ.jpg" width=100 height=100 class="thumb">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://scdn3.thomascook.com/crop?imageUrl=http://magnolia.production.thomascook.io/wcms/dam/tcuk/holidays/bulgaria/sunny-beach-in-BULGARIA.jpg&maxWidth=300&maxHeight=0" width=100 height=100 class="thumb">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.targetwoman.com/image/myrtle-beach-resort.jpg" width=100 height=100 class="thumb">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.st-maarten-island-guide.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/St-Martin-Beach-Le-Gallion-300x300.jpg" width=100 height=100 class="thumb">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/bcxz1gnc/

Comment: Could you explain what is the window class that you used?

Comment: Yes, I just needed to name the image something so I could replace the src. I though window was a good name.

Answer (score 0):

I've got your point. You need to do it in JavaScript way. You should get smaller images **src attribute** in an array and then on hover give **each** of these **src** to your desired image. In this way you don't need to change your markup.

```js
$(".smallerImagesContainer img").each(function() {
    // mouseenter is hover for JQuery, mouseleave is like UnHover also
    $(this).on("mouseenter", function() {

        var smallerImagesSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        // Below line is where we replace Src
        $(".biggerImageContainer img").attr("src", smallerImagesSrc);

        // Just for checking!, Delete it later
        console.log(smallerImagesSrc + " replaced");
 alert(smallerImagesSrc + " replaced");
        
    });
});
```

```css
.biggerImageContainer {background-color: blue}
.biggerImageContainer > img {width: 100%; min-height: 250px; border: 2px solid gray;}
  
.smallerImagesContainer > img {width: 30%; min-height: 50px; border: 2px solid gray;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="biggerImageContainer">
    <img src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="smallerImagesContainer">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1">
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2">
    <img src="image3.jpg" alt="image3">
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pooria_h/rcpcbq7e/

**Don't forget to:**

1. Execute function after window loads. For suggestion put your code inside `$(window).load(function() {  })`
2. Hover in JavaScript is an event and `mouseenter` is JQuery keyword for hover. You can use `mouseleave` if you want to do else when mouse pointer is out.
3. JQuery `attr` in this way returns a relative link, if you want an absolute link you should use `prop` instead.

**Update:** I've noticed you didn't tagged Javascript in your question. In this case Answer 1 is what you need to do. But of course you should change your markup.